# calculate compound interest reversed in php

Tags: php, calculation

Given an initial investment (say $10,000), I would like to use php to calculate how much you would need to return each day to double your money in a year.

Seems easy as you could just divide investment by work days per year, but this doesn't take into account  you are continually increasing your capital.

I feel like I'm looking for some kind of daily compound interest function, but it has to run in reverse.... not giving you accrued interest, but starting at double your investment and working backwards.

Comment: if `i` is the interest rate in %, then `(1+i/100)^365=2` => `i = 0.19%`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i'm not sure how to get this calculation into PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you are looking for is (assuming you have compounding on all 365 days, many financial institutions assume 360 days in a year instead):

```
(1+i/100)^365=2
```

or to get the interest rate (in %),

```
i = (2^(1/365)-1)*100
```

in PHP the exponentiation operator is [`**`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

```
echo round((2**(1/365)-1)*100, 2) . "%\n";
```

Output (rounded to 2 decimal places using [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)):

```
0.19%
```